# ¿Como añadir un icono a mi aplicación en mi menú de android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Bueno lo que quiero realizar es que cuando se cargue mi vista con mi actionbar, al darle clic se desplieguen los menus y que cada menú tenga una pequeña imagen como icono.

Así declare mi menú en la carpeta de res con el nombre de menú y la imagen esta en la carpeta drawable con extensión .png

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <group>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_1"
        android:title="@string/Menu1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:showAsAction="always"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_2"
        android:title="@string/Menu2" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_3"
        android:title="@string/Menu3" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

pero al abrir la aplicación en mi celular no me muestra ninguna imagen en ningún menú.

Comment: David he agregado una respuesta.

Comment: si, pero aun estoy viendo la opcion de realizarlo sino pues entonces la pondre como correcta

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la **[documentación](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu)**:
**Si desarrollaste tu aplicación para Android 3.0 (nivel de API 11) y versiones posteriores, los elementos del [menú](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) de opciones están disponibles en la barra de app.**

Desgraciadamente después de Android 3.0 no se puede agregar un icono al menú:

http://android-developers.blogspot.mx/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tendrías que cambiar tu targetSDK a una API anterior a 3.0 que no creo desees realizar esto en tu proyecto.

Comment: Quien me dio -1 imagino sabe como realizarlo  =) haha!

Answer (score -1):

La única opción de "evadir" el sistema es con iconos en el String de cada ítem. Es decir, lo que debes hacer es copiar un emoji y pegarlo en el texto de tu recurso String de tu proyecto.

Entonces se acabará viendo así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Y cómo se implementaría ese truco que sugieres? No caería mal algo de código/textos de ejemplo/lo que sea que se necesite para hacer esto! (Y una imagen más pequeña :P )

Comment: Hola! Lo único que debes hacer es copiar un emoji y pegarlo en el texto de tu recurso String de tu proyecto. Yo usé los de esta página https://es.piliapp.com/emoji/list/ nada del otro mundo bro. Saludos